# IF condition is TRUE, then CHANGE to VALUE function for XMM / SIMD

Tags: assembly, simd, sse

I'm currently doing a SIMD task for Assembly.

```
.data
   minValue real4 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

ChangeValue PROC
;Here is another code, not important right now
movups xmm0, [minValue]         
;XMM1 = 0000000000000000-0000000000000000 ;  0,  0,  0,   0
;XMM2 = 43695555C272AAA8-C2695554C1955554 ;233,-60,-58, -18
cmpleps xmm1, xmm2 ;FirstArgumentLessOrEqualSecondArgument
;XMM1 = FFFFFFFF00000000-0000000000000000 
;XMM2 = 43695555C272AAA8-C2695554C1955554
```

After that, I would like to do something like (pseudocode):

```
somefunction xmm1, xmmm2, 0
; this should work like this:
; if TRUE(first argument), change(second argument) to value(third argument)
```

Is there any way (any):

- function
- custom procedure
- ... anything?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: normal way is to use the compare result as a blend control, either manually or SSE4.1 `blendvps`.  For zero specifically, `andnps` or `andps`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks a lot! blendvps help here :)! Love you!